# Python Program keeps crashing while using the "while" function

Tags: python, crash

Edited:

```
import random  # needed to generate random numbers

def roll_until_doubles():
    die_one = random.randrange(1, 7)
    die_two = random.randrange(1, 7)
    counter = 0
    while die_one != die_two:
        die_one = random.randrange(1, 7)
        die_two = random.randrange(1, 7)
        counter+=1
    return counter


def main():
    counter = roll_until_doubles()
    number_of_games = int(input("How many games would you like to play? "))
    for i in range(number_of_games):
        roll_until_doubles()
    print "Congratulations!"
    print "It took you " + str(counter) + " many rolls to roll doubles!"


main()
```

Thanks! It isn't crashing anymore. However, I'm still struggling to figure out how to print the values of the dice. The output should be for example:

```
dice 1 = 5 and dice 2 = 6
dice 1 = 4 and dice 2 = 8 
Congratulations!
It took you 2 rolls to roll doubles!
```

But I'm getting this:

```
Congratulations!
It took you [x] rolls to roll doubles!
```

How do I print the dice values?

Comment: Is anything actually crashing? You have an infinite loop (`while die_one != die_two:` without changing either value inside the loop will just spin forever), but I can't imagine how that could crash; it would just mean you never get a response.

Comment: (Well, I suppose after a huge amount of time, `counter` would be so large it would raise a `MemoryError` when you try to increment it, but I doubt you're seeing that.)

Comment: Also, what website are you talking about here? This looks like code you just run at the command line—it takes `input` and then `print`s results, and it doesn't have any connection to any web anything.

Comment: Simple fix, your dice aren't rolling inside your while loop.  You are rolling them once before the loop, so if they happen to be NOT equal on the first roll then that loop will run forever

Comment: Thanks! It doesnt crash anymore...do you mind checking out my edited question?

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question for this, because the title has nothing to do with it any more. What is the actual problem? Put a `print` statement at the right place, and see to it that the dice values are available there. Your example is strange; shouldn't the last roll be a double?